# Spring Security: Login authentication controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to redirect back to the login page when the authentication fails along with some error messages. I am wondering how do we pass some sort of parameters to `/login` in the `security-context.xml` saying that this is unauthenticated and then attach some error text ?

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
                     username-parameter="email"
                     password-parameter="password"
                     default-target-url="/member/"
                     authentication-failure-url="/login"/>
```

`/login` is actually a Controller for returning the ModelAndView.

Answer (score 4):

Try simply appending a query parameter to the `authentication-failure-url` like this:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
                     username-parameter="email"
                     password-parameter="password"
                     default-target-url="/member/"
                     authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
```

Then, your login handler method can receive that optional query parameter, and manipulate the response accordingly. Something along these lines:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLoginPage(
        @RequestParam(required = false) boolean error,
        ModelMap model) {

    model.put("error", error ? "You have entered an invalid username or password!" : "");

    return "loginpage";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an AuthenticationFailureHandler that will react differently depending on the AuthenticationException you will receive.

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
    username-parameter="email"
    password-parameter="password"
    default-target-url="/member/" 
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthenticationFailudeHandler"/>
```

For instance, it can redirect the user to .../login?errorCode=errorCode1

Then you can modify the controller to react to different error codes :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLoginPage(
        ..., 
        @RequestParam(value="errorCode", required = false) String errorCode, 
        Model model, 
        ... ) {
    if (errorCode != null) {
        model.put("error", translateErrorCode(errorCode));
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this

```
<security:form-login login-page="/" authentication-failure-url="/myapp/auth/login?error=true" default-target-url="/myapp/main/default"/>
```

And the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView indexp(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) boolean error, ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("view");
// return your view....
}
```

The parameter helps to display an error message.